# Finding first element in a Left-Child Right-Sibling Tree

Tags: java, c++, binary-tree, traversal

In a recent interview, I was asked this question.
Given a left-child, right sibling tree, find the first node in the tree that holds a true value.  (first defined as on the highest level, answer could be implemented in either C++ or Java

My answer is below and I believe it works based on the test cases I have run so far.  I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.  I'm using 3 queues right now and that does not seem optimal.

```
private class Node{
    Node child;
    Node sibling;
    boolean data;
}

Node findFirstTrue(Node n)
   {
    if (n == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (n.data == true)
    {
        return n;
    }
    Queue<Node> searchNextSibling = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
    Queue<Node> searchNextChildren = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
    searchNextSibling.add(n);
    while(!searchNextSibling.isEmpty() || !searchNextChildren.isEmpty())
    {
        while(!searchNextSibling.isEmpty())
        {
            Node current = (test.Node) searchNextSibling.remove();
            if (current.data == true)
            {
                return current;
            }
            if (current.sibling != null)
            {
                searchNextSibling.add(current.sibling);
            }
            if (current.child != null)
            {
                searchNextChildren.add(current.child);
            }

        }
        Queue<Node> tempQueue = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
        while (!searchNextChildren.isEmpty())
        {
            Node current = (test.Node) searchNextChildren.remove();
            if (current.data == true)
            {
                return current;
            }
            if (current.sibling != null)
            {
                searchNextSibling.add(current.sibling);
            }
            if (current.child != null)
            {
                tempQueue.add(current.child);
            }

        }
        searchNextChildren.addAll(tempQueue);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Comment: Also, this could be best for [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: oh because the answer could have been in either C++ or Java

Comment: Okay.  In that case, you could mention that in the question so as to not confuse others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise solution written in C#, but would be almost identical to a java one:

```
    private Node VisitSiblings(Node node, Queue<Node> q)
{
    if (node == null || node.Flag) return node;
    q.Enqueue(node);                           
    return VisitSiblings(node.Sibling, q);     
}

public Node ReturnFirstTrueNode(Node root)
{
    Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();

    Node node = VisitSiblings(root, q);  
    if (node != null) return node;    
    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        node = q.Dequeue();
        Node x = VisitSiblings(node.Child, q); 
        if (x != null) return x;  
    }
    return null;  
}
```